# How do I start the game Quintet?

Tags: games, binary

I downloaded the linux version of the game [Quintet](https://www.quintet.us/) on a machine with Ubuntu 13.10, but now I don't know how to start the program. The main file is simply named `Quintet.x86`. Double clicking does nothing. The terminal does not recognize it as a command. In properties, the button "Allow executing file as a program" is checked.

I'm not sure what I need to do here. Help?

Edit to add: 
The command `file Quintet.x86` gave this response-

```
Quintet.x86: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, BuildID[sha1]=0x3a98f0f283fcfa52e2e34c49f259beb084c55f8f, stripped
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go into the directory where `Quintet.x86` file is placed.
- Then run `./Quintet.x86` command.

Comment: I did, and found that I was missing some dependencies. Program runs! *BUT* somehow doing this broke my sound. How the hell did that happen? Arg.

Comment: you can run any script file by `./filename` or `bash filename`